# Trying to cache dynamically load js

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

I'm trying to cache dynamically load js. Commented, the options that I tried:

```
// $.ajaxSetup ({
//     cache: true
// });

loadScript = function (url, callback) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'script',
        cache: true,
        success: callback,
        async: true,
        // ifModified: true
    });
}
```

Calling it like so:

```
loadScript('/'+'{{ $js }}').done(function() {
    // ...
});
```

It never caches...

[image]

Comment: Is Disable Cache turned off in the Developer Tools?

Comment: nope, nope, nope :)

Comment: Haha did that fix it?

Comment: I mean no, it was not checked. I has to be unchecked for what I understood, but tried both anyways

Comment: It works on deploy but not on local. I think php artisan serve and php -S localhost don't support cache?

Comment: Glad to hear it's working though

Comment: Yes so the code should be fine and should be a server unsupported/config issue